# how to load an element without loading the entire page

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I have google analytics graph in my home page, via google charts api, and it takes lot of time to load the entire page. If the charts are turned off the page loads faster.

how can i load the entire page quickly and then allow google charts to show using loading.gif. I think its Ajax, 
cant figure out how and where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load Individual Div without load entire page and show loading status?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855924/how-do-i-load-individual-div-without-load-entire-page-and-show-loading-status)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to hold off loading the image until the rest of the page has loaded.  No AJAX required.  Just move the scripts to the bottom of the page, immediately before the closing body tag.

So, looking at this page:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts.html - The drawChart() function won't be called until the last possible moment.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but i want the part to load after the entire page gets loaded ( i dont want the spinning gif to revolve in my browser tab, that increases my page loading time.). i hope you get my point.

Comment: That won't increase or decrease your page loading time, you're just fiddling figures and your criteria for measuring it.  Some browsers will revert back to the 'spinning gif' whenever a new resource is requested.  You can delay the loading of the IMG by calling drawChart via setTimeout.